# How did C++ compilers implemented fold-expressions in C++17?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++17, variadic, fold-expression

I looked around the web to understand how did these highly simple-to-use expressions implemented behind the scenes, and I couldn't find anything that relates to the implementation of those expressions.

For example:

```
template<typename ...Types>
struct my_struct {
    static_assert((std::is_integral<Types>::value && ...), "All types must be integrals");
};
```

Or:

```
template <typename T>
auto func1(const T param) {
    return paramm * (param + 1);
}

template <typename ...Types>
auto func2(const Types... params){
    return (func1(params) + ...);
}
```

I only found the recursive ways in C++11 & C++14, but I couldn't find anything about the compiler intelligent way of understanding these expressions.

#### I'll try to better explain my question:

Does the compiler convert the fold expression to a C++ simpler code (and if it does, does it happens recursively, or within a regular loop) before compiling it to assembly?
It might be better to ask about the general way of compiling variadic expressions into assembly, but in C++11/C++14 it is a lot more closer to C syntax then it in C++17 with fold-expressions. It just look not trivial to implement in a low level language.
To put more focus on this question- if it possible, and you know an open-source compiler which have this feature (fold-expression), refer your answer to this compiler (although I do look for a more general answer if exists).

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for exactly? You want to see the compiler source code that converts fold expressions into assembly?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. This isn't a difficult feature to implement in a compiler; it just has to unroll the parameter pack. Everything happens at compile time, similar to (but simpler than) if it were a recursive template instantiation.

Comment: consider `template <typename ...Types>` as a shortcut for writing templates with all possible number of parameters, then once the templates are instantiated the fold expression is simply about expanding the expression with the known types. I dont think there is much magic to it. The big leap was variadic templates with c++11, but I don't really understand what "intelligent" explanation you are looking for fold expressions

Comment: @Brian I want to understand the general idea of how this topic implemented. Of all the features in C++, this specific feature makes C++ to look (from my point of view, maybe too much years with C++ have some effect on it) a lot more closer to high level languages, than the other features.

Comment: @Sneftel I am trying to understand if the compiler compiles this code into an expended C++ and then into assembly, or does it go straight to assembly?

Comment: @Sneftel I tried to enter more details about the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @KorelK Your question is basically about compiler design in general. The answer to the question "expanded C++ or assembly directly" is "it depends" and "neither". First, it depends on the compiler. Second, compilers have internal representations (usually more than one) they work with, and template instantiation happens on one of them, not in C++ source form. Though token substitution the way VC++ did it until recently comes close.

Comment: Which compiler? There are many compilers with different implementations.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Just edited my question: `To put more focus on this question- if it possible, and you know an open-source compiler which have this feature (fold-expression), refer your answer to this compiler(although I do look for a more general answer if exists).`. I am trying to understand how does a feature that change the language syntax from multiple functions/structs compile time recursion, into a single line recursion implemented.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I understand. Can you give a single example from one compiler of implementation?

Comment: Suppose you are given an example and an explanation, for some particular compiler. How exactly does that help you, and what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? If you are trying to learn something about compilers in general, you surely must understand that this is an infinitesimally small part of what a C++ compiler does, and even knowing how a particular compiler implements this narrow task doesn't really tell you much at all. If you want to learn about how compilers work, this is a formal course of study.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just want to understand how this specific feature implemented in a low level language. I don't want to learn how to build a compiler, I just learned recently about this feature, and it looks extremely non trivial feature for this language. It's not a new function, an optimization attribute, library- it's a new syntax for recursive analyze of variadic templates/functions. I want to understand how this new syntax entered into this language. I believe that this is not a pointless question, but it might not be the right place to ask, please let me know what you think.

Comment: The formal specification of the C++ programming language runs to about two thousand pages of terse, single-spaced text. Compiling C++ code is not just a one shot deal. Put in C++ code into one hole, push a button, and out comes out runnable code is not how it happens. C++ compilation takes place in multiple discrete phases, starting with the preprocessor, proceeding to lexical analysis, then grammar parsing, etc... Implementation of fold expressions, typically, involves multiple phases. In a typical C++ compiler there is no single function whose job is to compile a fold expression.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think it's pretty much answering my question, I were only aware of the top-level compilation levels which are preprocessing, compilation, and linking. I do think it's worth a response, but it depends on the reopening of this question.

Comment: It really isn't that complicated once you already have template pack instantiation in general. But unless you first understand template instantiation, understanding fold expression instantiation is not really useful because you have no context to put it in.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I do understand template instantiation, and I know it for more than 2 years now, and I do understand the use of fold-expressions, and the fold expression instantiation- I just wanted to understand how does the compiler unfolding the fold expression. Practically, as I mentioned in the edit, it would be better to ask how does C++ compiler handle the variadic templates/functions, but I wanted to give the focus to the thing that I really wanted to understand and it is the way the compiler reads and translate the fold-expressions- especially because it's like a new syntax to C++.

Comment: You can see for yourself [how gcc does it](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/a4c3da45a877599791191334536d1a1f155f50e1). The entire feature fits into a single quite-readable commit. It is not a macro, and it is not generated directly to assembly language. Compilers don't work that way. It goes into the parse tree (parser.c), then gets converted within the AST into simpler nodes (pt.c), just like any other AST node. (I found this by searching for "fold expression" in the commit history. Only 27 hits, and the commit titles are quite clear, so the search went quickly.)

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks a lot! I think you can post it as a response.

Comment: My response was just a sketch, not an answer. You can flesh it out to an answer and accept it.